# TableViewCell is not showing alertView

Tags: ios, uitableview

In `OrderFormViewController` I've a `tableView` and the tableViewCell I've a `cameraButton` that will show an alert when tapped.

Now when `OrderFormViewController` is presented *(not pushed)* it loads `tableView` and it's cell *(Row count is 1 hard coded)*.

I've the following code under the `IBAction` of `cameraButton`:

```
@IBAction func cameraButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        //DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image From", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera))
                {
                    self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
                    self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
                    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                else
                {
                    let alert  = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "You don't have camera", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }))

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
                self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
                UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }))

            //alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        //}
    }
```

I've searched for this so this is why I tried `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController` and also tried to run it from `DispatchQueue.main.async` but some how `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)` is not working.

**UPDATE** If I push the view controller then it works. But I need a solution for presented view controller.

Comment: Why don't you use `self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)` ?

Comment: use delegate pattern to delegate the presentation task to `OrderFormViewController` and there you can present it regardless of how did `OrderFormViewController` get to the screen.. see my answer for more details

Comment: @Venkat because it's tableViewCell and it doesn't have self reference.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend refactoring the whole solution to use delegates - delegate the action of presenting the alert from `UITableViewCell` to `OrderFormViewController`, and there simply use

```
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Because using `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController` is really fragile.

So just to sketch it up for you, I believe the best approach is this:

```
class OrderFormViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        // set the delegate
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}

extension OrderFormViewController: CustomCellDelegate {
    func customCellDelegateButtonPressed(_ customCell: CustomCell) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image From", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        // configure the alert

        // now the presentation of the alert is delegated here to OrderFormViewController, so it can simply use self to present
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

protocol CustomCellDelegate: class {
    func customCellDelegateButtonPressed(_ customCell: CustomCell /*, potentially more parameters if needed */)
}

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    // rest omitted for brevity

    weak var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func cameraButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.customCellDelegateButtonPressed(self)
    }
}
```